# How to create script for run sudo mount -a

Tags: automount

I'm very very new for ubuntu. I have one raspberry with ubuntu-mate os. Now I got one problem with it.

I edit fstab on `/etc/fstab` for mount share folder from windows server. It works fine after I do `sudo mount -a`.

but after reboot it can't mount on Startup. I must to open terminal and run command `sudo mount -a` every time after reboot.

How can I do the script for run `sudo mount -a` when ubuntu start.

Or I can make the script run `sudo mount -a` by double click like .bat for Windows.

My `fstab`:

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0 
/dev/mmcblk0p2 / ext4 defaults,noatime 0 1 
/dev/mmcblk0p1 /boot/firmware vfat defaults 0 2 

//myservername/data/Departments/ /home/raspberry01/Desktop/WI cifs,_netdev,auto,rw,username=mydomianusername,password=mypassword 0 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run scripts on start up?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Could you please post your `/etc/fstab`?  @heemayl I don't think that's accurate.

Comment: @earthmeLon   My fstab


proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
/dev/mmcblk0p2  /               ext4   defaults,noatime  0       1
/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot/firmware  vfat    defaults          0       2


//myservername/data/Departments/  /home/raspberry01/Desktop/WI cifs ,_netdev,auto,rw,username=mydomianusername,password=mypassword 0 0

Comment: @suchartsaeung Would be nice if you could include your fstab in the question and not in a comment, so that it is easier readable. You can modify your question by clicking "edit".

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that

```
//myservername/data/Departments/ /home/raspberry01/Desktop/WI cifs,_netdev,auto,rw,username=mydomianusername,password=mypassword 0 0
```

should be

```
//myservername/data/Departments/ /home/raspberry01/Desktop/WI cifs _netdev,auto,rw,username=mydomianusername,password=mypassword 0 0
```

The file system "cifs" is a column of it's own and the options come afterwards. You concatenated both and that would be wrong syntax.